# Coding bat (Python > List-2 > has22)

Tags: python

[link](http://codingbat.com/prob/p119308)

the answer is

```
def has22(nums):
  for i in range(0, len(nums)-1):
    #if nums[i] == 2 and nums[i+1] == 2:
    if nums[i:i+2] == [2,2]:
      return True    
  return False
```

I don't understand why there's a "-1" after len(nums). This question is probably more algebra related...

Comment: Please post the assignment. Links tend to break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start counting arrays with the number 0,so the first element in an array is the 0th element.

If an array has three elements a, b, c. The indexes would be 0, 1, 2 but the length would be 3.

Therefore:
If you want to loop through all the indices you would want to go from

> 0..2

or

> 0 .. length - 1

Answer (score 1):

```
def has22(nums):
  istwo=0
  for i in nums:
    if i==2:
      if istwo:
        return True
      else:
        istwo=1
    else:
      istwo=0
  return False
```

I think **FLAGS** are better {more human readable} solution to this kind of problems. its simple as well.

Comment: yes it works and easy to understand.Although Haris reddy's solution works but it is hard to understand

Answer (score 0):

```
def has22(nums):
  if len(nums) < 2:
      return False
  
  for i in range(0,len(nums)-1):
      while nums[i] == 2 and nums[i+1] == 2:
          if nums[i] == 2 and nums[i+1] == 2:
              return True
              i += 1
          else:
              return False
              i += 1
  
  for i in range(0, len(nums)-1):
      if nums[i] !=2 and nums[i]!= 2:
          return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def has22(nums):
  i = 0
  while i < len(nums) -1:
    return (nums[i] == 2 and nums[i+1] == 2) or (nums[i-1] == 2 and nums[i-2] == 2) or (nums[i-2] == 2 and nums[i-3] == 2)
  if len(nums) < 2:
    return False
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

A more readable solution:

```
def has22(nums):
  if not nums or len(nums) == 1: return False
  prev = None
  for i, number in enumerate(nums):
    if number == prev: return True
    prev = number
  return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Refreshed, and simple

```
def has22(nums):
      if len(nums)>2:
        for i in range(len(nums)-1):
          if nums[i] == 2 and nums[i+1] == 2:
            return True
        else:
          return False
      if len(nums) == 2:
        return nums == [2,2]
      return len(nums) > 2
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
def has22(nums):
  has22 = False
  for i in range(1, len(nums)):
    if nums[i] == nums[i-1] and nums[i] == 2:
      has22 = True
      break
    
  return has22
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def has22(nums):
  if not nums or len(nums) == 1:
    return False
  prev = None
  for number in nums:
    if number == prev and number ==2:
      return True
    prev = number
  return False
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).